# XML to SQL table (epcis:EPCISDocument)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

Could you help me here, please? I need to do a query with an XML file, however, it has something different because it has the `epcis:` at the beginning of the XML document.

So, if I try to do the query with `epcis:` and `dts:` the result is:

> Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Line 38.
> XQuery [nodes()]: The name "epcis" does not denote a namespace.

And if I try to do the query without `epcis:` and `dts:`, the result is in blank.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @archivo XML
    SET @archivo = (
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <epcis:EPCISDocument xmlns:dts="urn:dts:extension:xsd" schemaVersion="1.2" creationDate="2021-06-30T07:29:32.6511940Z"
                xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1">
                <EPCISBody>
                    <EventList>
                        <ObjectEvent>
                            <eventTime>2021-06-30T07:29:32</eventTime>
                            <eventTimeZoneOffset>+02:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
                            <action>OBSERVE</action>
                            <bizStep>code</bizStep>
                            <dts:epcItemList>
                                <item>
                                    <epc>123456789</epc>
                                    <code>123456789zz</code>
                                </item>
                                <item>
                                    <epc>9687654321</epc>
                                    <code>9687654321zz</code>
                                </item>
                                <item>
                                    <epc>147258369</epc>
                                    <code>147258369zz</code>
                                </item>
                            </dts:epcItemList>
                        </ObjectEvent>
                    </EventList>
                </EPCISBody>
            </epcis:EPCISDocument>'
    )


    SELECT 
        patch.r.value('(epc)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [epc],
        patch.r.value('(code)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [code]
    FROM  
        @archivo.nodes('EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/ObjectEvent/epcItemList/item') AS patch(r)
END 
GO
```

I need to export the information as a SQL table per item, like this:

```
| epc        | code         |
| --------   | ------------ |
| 123456789  | 123456789zz  |
| 9687654321 | 9687654321zz |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2XyI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nkwk.png)

Thank you so much
Juan

Answer (score 1):

**You need to declare your namespaces.** The namespace aliases present in the XML are not relevant, you can use any alias you like (that's the bit after `AS` in the declaration).

> Also, `text()` is more performant when used in `.value`

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1' AS epcis,
  'urn:dts:extension:xsd' AS dts
)
    SELECT 
        patch.r.value('(epc/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [epc],
        patch.r.value('(code/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [code]
    FROM  @archivo.nodes('epcis:EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/ObjectEvent/dts:epcItemList/item') as patch(r);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/133123)